# Unable to retrieve images in View in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have uploaded images in storage folder. Now I want to retrieve the images in the view. I am working local environment right now. `<img src={{ Storage::disk('local')->url($image->path) }}>` doesn't to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe your storage directory not accessible for client?

Comment: For me I will do like that `{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $image->path }}`. But, my image was store under `public/images` directory.

Comment: @KelvinKyaw Already used that. I am  trying to explore more about Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you have setup symlink properly between public and storage/app/public directories. You can do this by using this command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

For more info please have a look: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#configuration

In view, you can display an image like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset($image->path) }}" />
```

Also, make sure that you storing image path correctly in the database.

Comment: I did that `php artisan storage:link`. But didn't seem to work. Do I need to add `storage/about/image.jpg` in my database or `about/image.jpg` is fine?

Comment: Into the database, store image path relative to the public directory. So it will be like storage/about/image.jpg. Are you able to see any "storage" directory into the public directory? If yes then the symlink is setup properly.

Comment: I got that storage folder in public directory. I am getting the URL of images as `storage/about/image.jpg`. The database has `about/image.jpg` as the URL. What am I missing now?

Comment: In your database you need to store "storage/about/image.jpg" not just "about/image.jpg".

Comment: i did that. Still the same.

Comment: Print $image->path in the view and check that are you getting correct path or not?

Comment: I am getting `storage/about/image.jpg` as my path. The problem now is that its not visible in the view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135157/discussion-between-fahad-iqbal-ahmad-khan-and-parth-vora).

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a function that receives either a name or a an ID of an model or whatever you have and return the image according to some logic?
For example :

1. Get the filename(if you save it under a folder make sure to save
   folder/filename.extension, if)
2. Search for it and get the file in the correct storage
3. Return the file with the correct headers
4. Make a GET route that recieves as a parameter the filename and call
   a funtion has shown below

> ```
>  // Controller
> public function getImage(Request $request){
>    $filename = $request->filename;
>    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);
>    return response($file)->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => "image/png"]);
> }
>
>
>  // Route
> Route::get('/getThisImage/{filename}',[
>  'uses'=>'HomeController@getImage',
>  'as'=>'getImage'
> ]);
>
> // Example of calling it in blade
> <img src="{{route('getImage')}}/{{$image->path}}">
> ```